# H2O sparkling water error from large Spark Dataframe to H2O Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, h2o, sparklyr, sparkling-water

When I try to convert from spark dataframe to H2O data frame I get the error below. This seems to have to do with the size of the dataframe because when I make it smaller the converter between spark and H2O works well.

Are there any configurations that need to be changed in order to convert large spark dataframes to H2O using sparkling water? In my configuration I am allowing max memory to the driver and executor so this is not a memory issue.

I am using R here the code is:

```
training<-as_h2o_frame(sc, final1, strict_version_check = FALSE)
```

Error:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 95.1 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.3 in stage 95.1 (TID 4050, 10.0.0.9): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65535
                at water.DKV.get(DKV.java:202)
                at water.DKV.get(DKV.java:175)
                at water.Key.get(Key.java:83)
                at water.fvec.Frame.createNewChunks(Frame.java:896)
                at water.fvec.FrameUtils$class.createNewChunks(FrameUtils.scala:43)
                at water.fvec.FrameUtils$.createNewChunks(FrameUtils.scala:70)
                at org.apache.spark.h2o.backends.internal.InternalWriteConverterCtx.createChunks(InternalWriteConverterCtx.scala:29)
                at org.apache.spark.h2o.converters.SparkDataFrameConverter$.org$apache$spark$h2o$converters$SparkDataFrameConverter$$perSQLPartition(SparkDataFrameConverter.scala:95)
                at org.apache.spark.h2o.converters.SparkDataFrameConverter$$anonfun$toH2OFrame$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(SparkDataFrameConverter.scala:74)
                at org.apache.spark.h2o.converters.SparkDataFrameConverter$$anonfun$toH2OFrame$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(SparkDataFrameConverter.scala:74)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
                at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
                at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
                at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
                at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1667)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1622)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1611)
                at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
                at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1873)
                at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1886)
                at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1906)
                at org.apache.spark.h2o.converters.WriteConverterCtxUtils$.convert(WriteConverterCtxUtils.scala:83)
                at org.apache.spark.h2o.converters.SparkDataFrameConverter$.toH2OFrame(SparkDataFrameConverter.scala:74)
                at org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OContext.asH2OFrame(H2OContext.scala:145)
                at org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OContext.asH2OFrame(H2OContext.scala:143)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at sparklyr.Invoke$.invoke(invoke.scala:102)
                at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:89)
                at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.read(stream.scala:54)
                at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:49)
                at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
                at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
                at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
                at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
                at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
                at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
                at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
                at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
                at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
                at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65535
                at water.DKV.get(DKV.java:202)
                at water.DKV.get(DKV.java:175)
                at water.Key.get(Key.java:83)
                at water.fvec.Frame.createNewChunks(Frame.java:896)
                at water.fvec.FrameUtils$class.createNewChunks(FrameUtils.scala:43)
                at water.fvec.FrameUtils$.createNewChunks(FrameUtils.scala:70)
                at org.apache.spark.h2o.backends.internal.InternalWriteConverterCtx.createChunks(InternalWriteConverterCtx.scala:29)
                at org.apache.spark.h2o.converters.SparkDataFrameConverter$.org$apache$spark$h2o$converters$SparkDataFrameConverter$$perSQLPartition(SparkDataFrameConverter.scala:95)
                at org.apache.spark.h2o.converters.SparkDataFrameConverter$$anonfun$toH2OFrame$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(SparkDataFrameConverter.scala:74)
                at org.apache.spark.h2o.converters.SparkDataFrameConverter$$anonfun$toH2OFrame$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(SparkDataFrameConverter.scala:74)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
                at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
                at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                ... 1 more
```

Comment: It seems like your H2O cloud is not properly initialized. Please check the readme here https://github.com/h2oai/rsparkling#spark-connection

Answer (score 0):

going to repost Jakub's comment so it is more easily found:

It seems like your H2O cloud is not properly initialized. Please check the readme here github.com/h2oai/rsparkling#spark-connection